# Angular 8 basic interceptor not called on page loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interceptor, angular8

I'm in the process of adding an interceptor to my angular 8 project. To make add bearer token. Unfortunately the interceptor does not seem to be called. My code:

## I already:

1. Added `HttpClientModule`, `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` and `HttpConfigInterceptor` imports in app.module.ts file.
2. Added `HttpClientModule` in `imports` section after `BrowserModule`.
3. Added `{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpConfigInterceptor, multi: true }` in providers section.

app.module.ts file:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpConfigInterceptor } from './httpconfig.interceptor';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PrivacyPolicyComponent } from './privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component';
import { TermsOfUseComponent } from './terms-of-use/terms-of-use.component';
import { SnippetsComponent } from './snippets/snippets.component';
import { SnippetComponent } from './snippet/snippet.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PrivacyPolicyComponent,
    TermsOfUseComponent,
    SnippetsComponent,
    SnippetComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    Title,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpConfigInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My interceptor file:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(request);
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

I want just the console.log works.

Thks ^^.

Comment: HttpConfigInterceptor should be added to providers

Comment: Do you have anything to intercept? HttpInterceptor triggers when you use HttpClient.

Comment: @MattWalterspieler, Thanks for your answer, i want just display my console.log in first time, after, it allow to add bearer token automatically. But, i don't understand why my console.log don't works !

Comment: @tano, Thanks for your answer, it already added in providers section.

Comment: @François the intercept method will trigger only if you have something to an http request to intercept. ie: this.httpClient.get('url') in a service will trigger the intercept method when called. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: @MattWalterspieler, Ohhhhh okay, it not possible to use it like a middleware ? On each pages loading ?

Comment: You might wanna check router guards: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: Thks ^^ @Matt Walterspieler